# Azure Function has IP address out of VNet's range

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure Function that uses the Premium Plan - I needed that to be able to integrate it with a Virtual Network on Azure. I have integrated my app with a VNet's subnet which has the address range `172.24.2.0/26`.

When I SSH into my Azure Function and run `ip a` command I see:

```sh
root@2a5f00591f61:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if36: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 82:4d:fd:69:94:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.129.3/24 brd 169.254.129.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vnet009kd8d60@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 62:6b:44:d9:b5:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 169.254.254.3/24 brd 169.254.254.255 scope global vnet009kd8d60
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I do not understand why none of the listed IPs is in my subnet's range. The reason why I created the Function in the Premium Plan was to have it in the VNet. My use case is that I have a service that accepts requests only from selected VNets - including the one my Function uses.
How do I make my function's IP to be in the subnet's range?

//EDIT
My function has `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` = `1` in its configuration.

Comment: Have you added the WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL with value 1 to the app settings of Azure Function?

Comment: Yes, I did that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#regional-virtual-network-integration). Sorry, forgot to mention, I'll edit my post.

Comment: VNet Integration gives your function access to resources in your VNet, but it doesn't grant inbound private access to your function from the VNet, if it is acceptable that go through a public network, how about using Azure function IP restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design behavior and I also get the same result when you access the SSH tool from Azure function after VNet integration. As I can see, Azure assigns the [Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) to the SSH host after integrating the Azure Function within a VNet.

In fact, we could check the private IP assigned to the instance via the environment variable **WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP** from Kudu console UI. Read [manage-vnet-integration](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet.md#manage-vnet-integration) for more details.

> The private IP assigned to the instance is exposed via the environment
> variable, WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP. Kudu console UI also shows the list of
> environment variables available to the Web App. This IP is assigned
> from the address range of the integrated subnet. For Regional VNet
> Integration, the value of WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP is an IP from the address
> range of the delegated subnet, and for Gateway-required VNet
> Integration, the value is an IP from the address range of the
> Point-to-site address pool configured on the Virtual Network Gateway.
> This is the IP that will be used by the Web App to connect to the
> resources through the Virtual Network.

For Linux app service plan,
[image]

For Windows app service plan,
[image]

In this case, if you have a service that accepts requests only from selected VNets, you can force all outbound traffic to be sent into your VNets by adding the application setting
`WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1` and you can use network security group rules to restrict traffic in that VNets.

Comment: Ok, that's quite confusing. So, VNet integration is kind of like connecting the VNet to a router, into which my Function's host's NIC is connected? And then, adding `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1` configures the route table on that "router" to send all the traffic to that VNet? Here's a small drawing that shows how I understand it: https://aggie.io/1qqf1uzae7 Basicaly, I see VNet as a kind of router. By default, my Function is just connected to internet. With VNet integration, my VNet is also accessible to my function, but function is in another network actually. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By the way, I think it all would be much more clear if Azure was able to show such diagrams - it would be much easier to understand what to expect from the setups that involve VNets.

Comment: Just edit my reply to make it clear, and basiclly, azure function is conneted to the Internet, with vnet integration, the function have a nic mounted in that integrated subnet. This makes the function app could make outbound calls from that vnet.  What changes for your app are the calls to service endpoint secured services, or RFC 1918 addresses go into your VNet. If WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL is set to 1, all outbound traffic can be sent into your VNet.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Honestly, it seems to me that Azure implements it all in a bit "hacky" way, the documentation should definitely be more clear about networking things.

Comment: If my reply makes sense，do you mind accepting it？

Comment: In the end, if I send some HTTP request to some service (and let's assume `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1`), the recipient sees the origin IP as an IP that belongs to my VNet's subnet?

Comment: Yes，it should be so.